# How can I change only inner part of a web page-static page?

Tags: javascript, html

I write a static web pages-no server at this point.All the Headers and footers for all pages are same. There 4  buttons on header. I want to change only the part of the page between header and footer when a button in the header is clicked. For example there are 4 buttons Home, Activities etc.. If i click activities then header and footer of page should remain and activities page should come in between header and footer. How can i do that? 
once again -no server at the moment so ajax will not work for me.
At this point I have the button codes(the page which displayed after I press the activities button for example)  in separate html files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried?

Comment: You'd need to add the content as hidden, then swap it in using JavaScript. Is that what you're hoping to do?

Comment: dont know what to try.I duplicate the header and footer for all pages.but this open every page in a new window.

Comment: FYI, Ajax can work with html files as well, you don't need a server to load parts...

Comment: Diodeus,yes.I think this will solve the problem.do you have an example that you know of?

Comment: just saw the IE doesn't support the hidden option.I need a solution which will be supported on chrome,firefox and  IE. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
  <input name="" type="button"onclick="hideLayer('btn2content'); hideLayer('btn3content'); hideLayer('btn4content'); showLayer('btn1content');" value="btn1" />
  <input name="" type="button"onclick="hideLayer('btn1content'); hideLayer('btn3content'); hideLayer('btn4content'); showLayer('btn2content');" value="btn2" />
  <input name="" type="button"onclick="hideLayer('btn1content'); hideLayer('btn2content'); hideLayer('btn4content'); showLayer('btn3content');" value="btn3" />
  <input name="" type="button"onclick="hideLayer('btn1content'); hideLayer('btn2content'); hideLayer('btn4content'); showLayer('btn4content');" value="btn4" />
```

The new area called "content-wrapper" (below) is where all your content will go; it's all shown on the same page.

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="btn1content" style="display:block;" onclick="">stuff</div>
  <div id="btn2content" style="display:none;">more stuff</div>
  <div id="btn3content" style="display:none;">other stuff</div>
  <div id="btn4content" style="display:none;">that stuff</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function hideLayer(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function showLayer(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'none')
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

No servers required :)

Comment: Thanks,ill try this code. 
Can it load html files uppon btn click or all the code need to be in the same single html file?

Thanks for your help

Comment: All the content for what used to be the centers of individual pages would now be inside the content wrappers.